# SSH Keys deny access after reboot

Tags: ssh, encryption

I use ssh to remote into my Ubuntu desktop.

I have set it up to use key based authentication and disabled using the password to log in.

I have also configured iptables to only allow ssh from my internal network and the IP from my work and dropped everything else for added security.

Anyways, I am only able to gain access if I am already logged in. If I remote in and reboot for any reason, I get the permission denied pubkey message and it refuses to let me in.

For kicks, I used team viewer to log into my machine. After I logged myself in via team viewer, It let me ssh into it again.

Is there a setting I may have forgot to check when editing my sshd_config file?

My home directory is encrypted if that makes any difference. This is possibly the culprit.

I originally configured everything on 16.04 but recently upgraded to 17.04. I left all configurations the same during the upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because ssh daemon can't access to your authorized_keys file.

Change `USERNAME` to your username.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/ssh/USERNAME
```

Copy your key

```
sudo cp /home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/USERNAME
```

Own it

```
sudo chown -Rf USERNAME.USERNAME /etc/ssh/USERNAME
sudo chmod 644 /etc/ssh/USERNAME/authorized_keys
```

Add the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

Source: [Passwordless SSH in Encrypted Home Directory](https://support.severalnines.com/hc/en-us/articles/212426943-Passwordless-SSH-in-Encrypted-Home-Directory)